# How to use same NavigationToolbar2Tk for multiple matplotlib plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I've got multiple pages in a notebook and have multiple graphs on each.

Is there a way to use one navigation toolbar for all graphs on a notebook page? Or how can I put each navigation toolbar directly underneath the graph it controls?

I've tried adding padx and pady which I thought would force it under the graph, but it keeps putting both toolbars underneath the Quit button.

I'm pretty new to Python and am really struggling to find an answer to this question!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as app
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
y = np.square(x)
z = x

#Make the root widget
root = app.Tk()

#Make the notebook
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack()
root.title("Test")

#plot first graph
f1 = app.Frame(nb)
nb.add(f1, text="Test")
app.Label(f1, text="Test window 1").pack(padx=5, pady=5)

fig1 = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig1.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, master=f1)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=app.TOP, fill=app.BOTH, expand=1)

#add toolbar
toolbar1 = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas1, f1)
toolbar1.update()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=app.TOP, fill=app.BOTH, expand=1)

#plot second graph
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
fig2.add_subplot(111).plot(x, z)

canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, master=f1)
canvas2.draw()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=app.TOP, fill=app.BOTH, expand=1, padx=5, pady=5)

#add toolbar
toolbar2 = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas2, f1)
toolbar2.update()
canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=app.TOP, fill=app.BOTH, expand=1)

app.Button(f1, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=50, pady=50)

nb.select(f1)

nb.enable_traversal()

#Enter the mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have tried my best to simplify it as much as I can, don't really know how to further simplify it and still reproduce the problem